# Find the sequence of columns that has maximum values

Tags: r

I have got a data frame where each column has values. Is there a way to create a new column and see the sequence of Max values columns. For example. Please refer my expected output

```
df
COlA    COlB    COLC    COLD
 34      40      4.5      50
 35      70      2.0      30
 90      40      4.0      10
```

Expected Output

```
df
COlA    COlB    COLC    COLD            NewCOl
 34      40      4.5      50      COLD  > COLB > COLA > COLC
 35      70      2.0      30      COLB > COLA > COLD > COLC
 90      40      4.0      10      COLA > COLB  > COLD > COLC
```

Answer (score 1):

We can reshape into 'long' format after creating a row number column, then create a new column by `paste`ing the 'name' column `ordered` based on descending values in 'value' column, reshape back into 'wide' format and `select` the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) #v 1.0.0    
library(stringr)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -rn) %>%
   # or use gather for older versions
   # gather(name, value, -rn) %>%       
   group_by(rn) %>% 
   mutate(NewCol = str_c(name[order(-value)], collapse=' > ')) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value) %>%
   # or use spread for older versions
   # spread(name, value) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(names(df), NewCol)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#   COlA  COlB  COLC  COLD NewCol                   
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                    
#1    34    40   4.5    50 COLD > COlB > COlA > COLC
#2    35    70   2      30 COlB > COlA > COLD > COLC
#3    90    40   4      10 COlA > COlB > COLD > COLC
```

---

Or another option is `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
df %>% 
   mutate(NewCol =pmap_chr(., ~ c(...) %>%
            {names(.)[order(-.)]} %>%
            str_c(collapse=" > ")))
```

If there are `character` columns, use `select_if`

```
df %>%
     mutate(NewCol = pmap_chr(select_if(., is.numeric), ~ c(...) %>%
              {names(.)[order(-.)]} %>%
            str_c(collapse=" > ")))
```

#### data

```
df <-  structure(list(COlA = c(34L, 35L, 90L), COlB = c(40L, 70L, 40L
), COLC = c(4.5, 2, 4), COLD = c(50L, 30L, 10L)),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks But I get error ````could not find function "pivot_longer"```` Is there any function to install ?

Comment: or `df$newcol <- apply(df, 1, function(x) paste(names(df)[rank(x)], collapse = " < "))`

Comment: Thanks Nate. But some issues. I checked it. The values are not as proper

Comment: will it defer if there are in Decimals? Like 0.5, 0.6.... I have edited my question

Comment: @DevP No, please check my upddate

Comment: Not sure why I am not able to install pivot Longer

Comment: @DevP what is the version of `packageVersion('tidyr')`. I used `1.0.0`

Comment: @DevP okay, that is the issue, as `pivot_longer/pivot_wider` got introdduceddi in1.0.0

Comment: Oh then is there any alternate for this?

Comment: @DevP. For your version, the `gather/spread` commented should work.  You can comment out the `pivot_longer/pivot_wider` lines and uncomment the `gather/spread` lines

Comment: I tried bit getting ````Error in stri_c(..., sep = sep, collapse = collapse, ignore_null = TRUE) : 
  object 'name' not found````

Comment: @DevP Are you getting error with `df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%gather(name, value, -rn) %>%   group_by(rn) %>% mutate(NewCol = str_c(name[order(-value)], collapse=' > '))`

Comment: the dataset is getting longer. You can try once

Comment: @DevP Then, you need the `spread`.  I was checking if you are getting error or not `df %>% mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%gather(name, value, -rn) %>% group_by(rn) %>% mutate(NewCol = str_c(name[order(-value)], collapse=' > ')) %>% spread(name, value)`

Comment: Perfect thanks. But I need to exclude 2 columns because there are characters. I tried with indexing but not working. Say I need to exclude first 2 columns

Comment: @DevP. In the second method, you can exclude those columns `pmap_chr(.[-(1:2)], .`

Answer (score 1):

In base R you could do it this way (correct solution only if there are no ties):

```
dat$NewCol <- by(
  unlist(dat),
  row(dat),
  function(x) paste(names(dat)[order(x, decreasing = T)], collapse = ' > ')
  )

dat

#   COlA COlB COLC COLD                    NewCol
# 1   34   40  4.5   50 COLD > COlB > COlA > COLC
# 2   35   70  2.0   30 COlB > COlA > COLD > COLC
# 3   90   40  4.0   10 COlA > COlB > COLD > COLC
```

Data:

```
dat <- structure(
  list(
    COlA = c(34L, 35L, 90L),
    COlB = c(40L, 70L, 40L),
    COLC = c(4.5, 2, 4),
    COLD = c(50L, 30L, 10L)
  ),
  class = "data.frame",
  row.names = c(NA,-3L)
)
```